# Component with attribute selector causes child elements not to render

Tags: angularjs, angular, attributes, components, selector

I have created a component with attribute selector. When I use this attribute, the child elements of the original element are not rendered. Is this normal? I want both the original children and the applied component to be rendered because I cannot do otherwise in svg which is my current concern.
There is a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/DVdhCv8HDFoZAWO1syHD?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[attr-component]',
  template: '<div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red">    </div>'
})
export class AttrComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'local-component',
  template: `
<div attr-component>
    <div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
</div>
`
})
export class LocalComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div><local-component></local-component></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

in the parent component for child components to be rendered

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLxUZLUhCnevxQEB1uSe?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'l try it to my svg components.

Comment: Haven't tried it with SVG myself yet. SVG has a few limitations. If something doesn't work just create another question.